# How to terminate the response in ASP.NET Web API method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method that calls a third party library. Deep in the bowels of that library it calls Response.Flush. This results in:

> Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

This behavior can be reproduced simply enough:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "ok");
    }
```

I've tried using Response.End and CompleteRequest after the Flush() but neither seem to prevent Web API from continuing to add headers to the response. Is there another Web API specific mechanism to short circuit the response?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest Response.End but it looks like you've already tried it.

Have you tried using Response.Headers.Remove? I found an article on CodeProject that may useful.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/785867/ASP-NET-MVC-Remove-IIS-Header-Bloat

It says:

> "In addition, while we’re in the global file, we can also eliminate
>   the "Server" header by adding a handler to PreSendRequestHeaders event
>   like this:"

```
app.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not that I want to remove headers, I want to stop processing so that Web API doesn't try to modify the response at all.